# Geometric Series in Sigma Notation with natural log

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, power-series, exponentiation, divergent-series

So I am trying to solve for this problem below, I attach a screenshot of it, but I just can't seem to find the answer. Is anyone able to solve this? (Extra note: U<sub>n</sub> = U<sub>r</sub>)

So for (a) I got 2(1-2<sup>-10</sup>), which i got from deriving the geometric series equation $$S_n = \frac{U_1(1-r^n)}{r-1}$$ Which I believe should be correct, but for question (b) I tried to change the sigma notation series $$\sum_{n=0}^{10} ln(0.5^n)$$ into the normal geometric series equation $$S_{10} = \frac{1(1-ln(0.5^{10}))}{1-ln(0.5^{10})}$$
But then I got different values for it. So, is there another method to get the exact value in the form of c ln d, where c and d is an integer? And is my answer for question (a) correct?

[See the problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xmrw8.png)

Comment: Why you tag your question measure theory ?! And please give context and efforts .

Comment: @Anonyme Sorry sorry, I just really don't understand the question, I don't really know what context can I put in there, as I have not make much progress, I am particularly stuck on question (b), and I'm a bit new to StackExchange I don't really know how to format math equations here.

Comment: It's okay but explain a little bit on what you are stuck and what you don't understand .

Comment: Thank for your editing . I up vote your question .

Answer (score 1):

(a) Given sum is nothing else than:

$\sum_{r=0}^{10}u_r=u_0+u_1+u_2+u_3+u_4+u_5+u_6+u_7++u_8+u_9+u_{10}$.

Next, we have $u_n=0.5^n$, so we have to find:

$0.5^0 + 0.5^1 + 0.5^2 + 0.5^3 + 0.5^4 + 0.5^5 + 0.5^6 + 0.5^7 + 0.5^8 + 0.5^9 + 0.5^{10}$.

It is easy to recognize that the given sequence $u_n$ is geometric sequence, so basically we have to find the sum of first $11$ members of it. To find such sum we can use well known formula, i.e.

$S_{11} = \frac{1 - (\frac{1}{2})^{11}}{1-\frac{1}{2}} = ... = \frac{2047}{1024} = \frac{2048-1}{2^{10}} = \frac{2^{11} - 2^0}{2^{10}}$.

Comment: Ok, I understood this section of it, but is there a possible way to write the exact value of the sum in terms of base 2?

Comment: Obtained result $\frac{2047}{1024}$ is a fraction which is simplified to lowest terms, so it is not possible to express it as a power with base 2...

Comment: @Brilliant Purnawan You weren't asked to express it as a *power* in base $2$, merely to write it in base $2$.  What is the binary expansion of $\ 2047\ $?  How many bits of this binary expansion are needed to represent the integer part of $\ \frac{2047}{1024}\ $?

Comment: I don't understand the binary expansion part of what you're trying to convey, but from what you told me that I merely only need to write it in base 2. So in this case $\sum_{n=0}^{10}{2^{-n}}$, should be satisfactory enough for the question right?

Comment: To @Brilliant Purnawan: Follow the answer given by **lonza leggiera**, here is my hint: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K16C6736hh4

Comment: @Brilliant Purnawan  Yes, that's the answer I was trying to suggest.  It therefore hardly matters if you didn't understand what I wrote, since you've now got the answer you need all by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The sum in part (b) is not a geometric series.  But we do know that $\ \ln\left(a^n\right)=n\ln(a)\ $ for any positive $\ a\ $, so $\ \sum_\limits{n=0}^{10}\ln\left(0.5^n\right)= \sum_\limits{n=0}^{10}n\ln(0.5)\ $.  Can you now work out the sum of this series?

Comment: Sorry, I understood the part where you derived $\ln(a^n)$ to $n \ln(0.5)$, but I still don't quite understand how I can get exact value of the sum of this series in terms of c $ln$ d, or is c simply 55, by adding all the n values, and d is 0.5? Is this possible? If yes, why is it?

Comment: Yes, the sum is $\ 55\ln(0.5)\ $, but  $\ 0.5\ $ is not an integer, and you were asked to write the sum as $\ c\ln(d)\ $ where $\ c\ $ and $\ d\ $ are both *integers*, so you still have a bit of work to do.  You should find the identity $\ \ln\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)=-\ln(a)\ $ of some use for this.

Comment: Oh, ok then thanks I understand it now, so it should be -55$ln$(2)